# Sharded MongoDb collection with ~1 million records - Aggregation $group is

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, sharding, mongodb-atlas, group

I am using Mongo Atlas as a service. We have a collection of around 1 million records. I have sharded the collection. Now the aggregation query is not returning the correct data.

Why $group is only returning 100k records?

[image]

Total Documents in the collection: 882496

Documents Count by $count: 882496

Documents Count by $group: 100,000

Connection string: mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.ohw5a.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: There is no specific behaviour associated with using the ``$group` and counting for sharded collections. If you have a $match stage and if you use a shard key it will access a particular shard.  You connect to the cluster via a `mongos` and access the sharded data.

Comment: @prasad_ yes thats correct. But the data being returned is not correct. $match is empty in the case shared. So ideally it should fetch the data from all shards and combine them and return that. But its not.

Comment: What do you mean by "Count by $count"? What is the command you run?

Comment: Is `cluster0.ohw5a.mongodb.net` the `mongos` router or one of your shards?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's the cluster address which mongo atlas is providing to connect with the cluster. I dont know how mongo atlas is managing that. But if that's the case, then why it's showing the correct result on count?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 
{$count: "employeeId"}

Comment: If you perform the same two queries - say from `mongo` shell (or `mongosh`) what are the results? Also, form the shell what's the result from `db.collection.countDocuments({})` ? What is the MongoDB version, the cluster configuration and Compass version?

Comment: @prasad_ thanks. Mongo shell is returning the correct data. So something wrong in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string you have mentioned in the answer corresponds to a replica set - which in a sharded environment corresponds to **ONE SHARD, which is clustered for HA**.

Hence the count is returning the count of documents that exists on that shard itself.

Connect to `mongos` and then run the query. It should work just fine.